# Access Control Entries - where can i get 'token'

Tags: azure-devops-rest-api

[API Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/security/access-control-entries/access-control-entries-set-access-control-entries?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1)

Azure DevOps Rest API:
[image: Azure DevOps Rest API]

I try use my personal access token to request, but it doesn't look like success.

Postman request:
[image: Postman request]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The token format is :

```
"token": "$PROJECT:vstfs:///Classification/TeamProject/projectid"
```

For example:

[image]

You could also get the token in Browser Network tab.

Here  are the steps:

1. Press F12 in Browser to open Browser Developer tool.
2. Manually change the permission and check the network record.
3. You can find the token info in Request Payload.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, from Browser Network tab get the token is available. But we want update repo/work item or other permission, there is a API can get different type token?